# Is there a way to bring up a Yii console like 'rails console'?

Tags: yii, yii2

Is there a way to interact with Yii on the command line with a console like `rails console`? I'd like to test DB and ActiveRecord calls.

Comment: Did you read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html ?

Comment: @soju That's for console applications, like a `rake task`. That's not the same as an interactive `rails console`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [yii-shell](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-shell). It's made by the Yii team. It works like `rails console`

### EDIT:

Sorry, I worked from the documentation of [yii-shell](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-shell) which is - at the time of this writing - but a promise.

This is how you can get a proper REPL working in Yii 2.

First, we would need to get Psysh. You can install it globally to play with it, but I recommend adding the following line to your `composer.json`

```
require-dev: {
    // ... some other packages ...
    "psy/psysh": "0.7.2"
}
```

Run `composer update` to get this package installed.

Now we need to add this to a controller. The way to call up the break point from a controller is `eval(\Psy\sh());`.

**Note that this would invoke the console for debugging. So if your app is served with Apache, Nginx, or any other server which is not tied to an interactive console, this is pointless**

For this to work, I have served the application using PHP's inbuilt server and Yii's wrapper for it.

### In Yii Basic App template...

```
cd /path/to/application
./yii serve localhost:12345
```

In any controller, ...say `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    eval(\Psy\sh()); // <-- debugger point
    return $this->render('index');
}
```

When you access this action via tha URL, it would hang on your browser. If you check back in the console, you would see an interactive shell which should work like `rails c`. Checkout the [Psysh Documentation](http://psysh.org) for more details. To exit this interactive console, type `exit`; this should return control back to PHP's inbuilt server. **Do not exit the interactive console with** `Ctrl-C` **as this would close the PHP's inbuilt server also.**

### In Yii Advanced App template...

Serving the application does not work at the moment since it defaults to serving the contents of `console/web` which doesn't exist. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/196) with Yii; you can follow along there if it interests you.

However, if you have console controllers, you can do the same thing we did for the basic app. When you run the console command, you should be presented with the same interactive debug console.

Comment: So sad. It doesn't work. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-shell/issues/8

Comment: @Chloe sorry about this. I have updated the answer with something I have tested. Hope this helps you

Comment: Cool! I got `nikic/php-parser v2.1.0 requires ext-tokenizer * -> the requested PHP extension tokenizer is missing from your system` and had to install the `php-tokenizer` package. Then I put `actionShell() {
    eval(\Psy\sh()); }` into a console command and now I can run `yii kw/shell`!

Answer (score 2):

1) Install https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-shell

```
composer require yiisoft/yii2-shell
```

2) `./yii shell`